# JavaFx wrong encoding in Intellij Mac

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, javafx, encoding

I made a JavaFX program but when I run it the text encoding is wrong.

[The Java program running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4b9E.png)

```
2021-05-21 20:55:30.060 java[9662:328105] CoreText note: Client requested name ".SFNS-Regular", it will get Times-Roman rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[NSFont systemFontOfSize:].
2021-05-21 20:55:30.060 java[9662:328105] CoreText note: Set a breakpoint on CTFontLogSystemFontNameRequest to debug.
2021-05-21 20:55:30.441 java[9662:328105] CoreText note: Client requested name ".SFNS-Regular", it will get Times-Roman rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[NSFont systemFontOfSize:].
2021-05-21 20:55:30.793 java[9662:328141] CoreText note: Client requested name ".SFNS-Regular", it will get Times-Roman rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[NSFont systemFontOfSize:].
```

Comment: Which are your Java/JavaFX versions?

Comment: [`.SFNS-Regular` related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66891857/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. In my case I was able to work around the error by switching the Module SDK from Java SDK 11.0.12 (latest version at time of writing this) to an older version: 11.0.8.

To change SDK in IntelliJ go to:
File -> Project Structure -> Modules

Download of Java 11.0.8 is available here:
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html